# How can I merge multiple charts?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I have 3 charts one bar plot and 2 lint plot
How can I merge them together and get one chart without disturbing their individual properties

Here is the code I m using to create 3 charts

```
ax = plt.subplots()
# creating axes object and defining plot
ax1 = dataset.plot(kind = 'bar', x = 'month', y = 'max_temp', color = 'lightblue', secondary_y = True, linewidth = 3, alpha=0.5, legend=False)

ax2 = dataset.plot(kind = 'line', x = 'month', y = 'min_temp', color = 'green', linewidth = 3,  marker='o', markerfacecolor='white', markersize=12, legend=False)
ax3 = dataset.plot(kind = 'line', x = 'month', y = 'max_temp', color = 'blue', linewidth = 3,  marker='o', markerfacecolor='white', markersize=12, legend=False)

ax1.invert_yaxis()
ax2.fill_between(dataset['month'], dataset['min_temp'], color='lightgreen', alpha=0.5)
ax3.fill_between(dataset['month'], dataset['max_temp'], color='lightblue', alpha=0.5)
#title of the plot
plt.title("Daily Forecast", loc='left')

#labeling x and y-axis

ax2.set_ylabel('Temperature (Degree °C)', color = "black")
ax1.set_ylabel('Rainfall (mm)', color = 'black')

#defining display layout


# plt.legend( bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1.35), loc='upper right')


plt.savefig('file_name.jpg', dpi=400)
#show plot
plt.show()
```

and from the above code this output I am getting in here

[image]

[image]

How can I combine them all in one and make I single charts without disturbing there properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use :

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4))
ax2 = ax.twinx()  # to isolate the line plots

dataset.plot(kind='bar', x='month', y='rainfall',
             color='lightblue', ax=ax, width=0.4, legend=False)

ax.invert_yaxis()  # to invert the y-axis for the bar plot

ax2.plot(dataset['month'], dataset['min_temp'], color='green',
         linewidth=3, marker='o', markerfacecolor='white', markersize=12)

ax2.fill_between(dataset['month'], dataset['min_temp'], color='lightgreen', alpha=0.5)

ax2.plot(dataset['month'], dataset['max_temp'], color='blue',
         linewidth=3, marker='o', markerfacecolor='white', markersize=12)

ax2.fill_between(dataset['month'], dataset['max_temp'], color='lightblue', alpha=0.5)

ax.set_ylabel('Rainfall (mm)', color='black')
ax2.set_ylabel('Temperature (Degree °C)', color='black')

ax.set_title('Daily Forecast', loc='left')

ax.yaxis.tick_right()
ax.yaxis.set_label_position('right')

ax2.yaxis.tick_left()
ax2.yaxis.set_label_position('left')

plt.show();
```

Output :

[image]

*Input used :*

```
np.random.seed(123456)

dataset = pd.DataFrame(
    {'month': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
     'max_temp': np.random.randint(25, 40, 5),
     'min_temp': np.random.randint(15, 25, 5),
     'rainfall': np.random.randint(30, 70, 5)}
)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked but the rainfall reading should be on the right side and should also start to reverse as I have shown in the image of rainfall

Comment: I updated my answer! Can you check ?

Comment: can you please help me with one more thing adding legend outside the chart and display values for each bar and line point ?

Comment: To avoid moving targets, I will not update the answer but I made this : https://pastebin.com/NPMDsbcw. I think it should give you what you expect or at least put you in the right way.